# Downloads from my mobile not appearing on computer - Samsung Galaxy

Tags: samsung, usb-connection-mode

I have connected my mobile (Samsung galaxy) with my HP laptop (Windows 7) and clicked "Open device to view files".

I click "Downloads" - that is, what I have downloaded on my mobile - then "videos".

But to view the videos it shows "copying..."

Have the videos been copied on my laptop? If 'Yes', where can I find them?

Comment: Yes they will be copied to PC before playing in a temporary location. I don't know the location but look here - Start>Run>%TEMP%

Answer (score 0):

It does that because it is copying the file via MTP. If you want to view the files on your computer it would be far easier and faster to simply copy them to your computer from the mobile. Each time you open a file from your mobile through your computer it will copy them which takes time.